# filtering report with datasheet form filter

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

**Problem:**  I created datasheet form using query. I use the same query to make report. When I filter datasheet form and then open my report, form’s filter doesn’t affect my report.

**What’s to achieve:** I would like to see the same data in my report and in my filtered form.

**Question:** Is there some trick to apply datasheet form filter to my report?

**Important:** I cannot use unbound fields in my form to filter query. It has to be “Excel like” idea of filtering. I mean, user should be able to click little triangle in every column of the datasheet form, opt in some data from a list and then open report. Report should “remember” form's filter settings.

Answer (score 1):

The Report is based on the Query so you cannot open the Report from the Database Window/Navigation Pane and easily have it's source data changed according to what is displayed on the open form. (It is possible, but requires some coding.)

You could place the form as a subform on a new, blank, form, so that you could then add a button to preview the Report.

The button would preview the report and include a `Filter`. This Filter could be copied from that currently in use by the subform:

```
Private Sub cmdPreview_Click()
    'Debug.Print Me.Controls("frmStaffFilter").Form.Filter
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptStaffFilter", acViewReport, , Me.Controls("sbfStaffFilter").Form.Filter
End Sub
```

(This is using the Where argument, not a named filter, which is the argument before this.)

---

Based on this, you could achieve what I first mentioned. You would use the Report's Open event to first check if the Form (and its subform) is currently open; then read and apply the Filter of the subform by adapting my code above.

Comment: OK, it took a while, but finally I got the idea. I've replaced your Where argument: 
Me.Controls("sbfStaffFilter").Form.Filter
by
Forms!sbfStaffFilter.Form.Filter
and it works perfectly now. Many thanks for your help, Andy G :)